Power BI - 4 months moving sales
Hoping somebody can help me with data modelling or DAX.
I have a dimension date table and a fact sales table connected by date_id, one-to-many relationship.
I need to create visuals showing 4 months moving sales.
e.g. it's April 2024, so I would need to visualise sum of total Sales for
Jan 2024 - Apr 2024
Sep 2023 - Dec 2023
May 2023 - Aug 2023
etc.

If it's May 2024, then it would change to:
Feb 2024 - May 2024
Oct 2023 - Jan 2024
Jun 2023 - Sep 2023

I can see there is help on quarters, but haven't seen anything on 4 months moving total.

Can you provide some data ?
